# Asynchronous language selector using i18next

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

I am using http://jamuhl.github.com/i18next to localize a static website.

My initialization script is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var setLng = $.url().param('setLng');
    if (setLng)
    {
      language_complete = setLng.split("-");
    }
    else
    {
      language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
    }
    language = (language_complete[0]);
    console.log("I speak (root): %s", language);

    i18n.init({ lng: language, debug: true }, function() {
        // save to use translation function as resources are fetched
        $(".tzm-i18n").i18n();
        $(".page-i18n").i18n();
        $(".menu-i18n").i18n();
        $(".user-i18n").i18n();
        $(".search-i18n").i18n();
        $(".footer-i18n").i18n();
    });
    // language selector
    var lngSld = false;
    $('.lng_trigger').click(function() {
```

And here is the HTML:

```
  <div id="page" class="page-i18n">
    <!--${languages} Bread crumbs -->
      <p data-i18n="welcome.p1"></p>
      <p data-i18n="welcome.p2"></p>
  </div>
  <li id="set-lang"><!-- Language selector -->
    <select id="source">
        <option selected="selected" value="br">Brasil</option>
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="de">Germany</option>
        <option value="in">India</option>
        <option value="jp">Japan</option>
        <option value="rs">Serbia</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="us">United States</option>
    </select>
  </li>
```

What is the correct way to set the language when `<select>` option is clicked and just pull the values for `<p data-i18n="welcome.p1"></p>` from the `/locals/br/translations.json` file asynchronously without having to reload the entire page?

How would this then be persisted, if the user then navigates to other pages?
I am using https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser but don't see any functions to alter the uri so that the choice is appended to like `http://domain.tld/br/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put the translation functions in a separate function (i.e. `translatePage()`) and call it the first time during `init` and a second time when the `click` event handler is fired.

Also, i18next comes with cookie storage (initialized with `useCookie: true`); you can use this to store your current language with `$.i18n.setLng` and retrieve it with `$.i18n.lng()` functions. Then it's easy to redirect to each URI.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

What manudurand said is correct. Also, you don't need to reload the page, just set the language and translate the strings again like this:

```
i18n.setLng('en-EN', function() { $('[data-i18n]').i18n(); });
```

However, in your case instead of...

```
$('[data-i18n]').i18n();
```

... it would be ...

```
    $(".tzm-i18n").i18n();
    $(".page-i18n").i18n();
    $(".menu-i18n").i18n();
    $(".user-i18n").i18n();
    $(".search-i18n").i18n();
    $(".footer-i18n").i18n();
```